# Notepad++ Search and Replace with Tab Delimited File

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

I have a file that is tab delimited. When exporting from Excel, if the cell has a comma in it, it will wrap the cell with double quotes.

To find the first double quote, I can look for a tab then double quote ex: `\t"`

The next double quote to remove is at the end of the line, so I would like to find double quote then newline ex: `\n"`   but this is not working.

Example of the file format:

`text`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`text`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`"moretextwithquotes"`<kbd>CRLF</kbd>

Comment: Newline is not \n but \r\n on windows

Comment: Another way to do this is to highlight from that last quote to the very beginning of the next line. Then ctrl+g. It will look like only the quote is in the "find" box, but N++ will have also copied in the necessary linefeed and/or carriage return characters as well.

Comment: "\r\n was what I needed

Comment: You can also try `\v+` which, if supported by N++, is a regex shorthand for "vertical whitespace character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're searching for `\n"` instead of `"\n`, if I well understand your problem.

Secondly, you need to search for `\r\n` instead of `\n`, so your final result should be `"\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

If all your data is consistent where double quotes are matched and encapsulates fields,
I would just do a global find and replace just on quoted text.
Replacing the match with just the field data. This strips the quotes, leaves everything
else untouched.

Find:  `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"`
Replace: `$1`